# Google Drive API grant access without manual authorization

Tags: google-drive-api

I am building a web application which facilitates its user to upload different types of documents. All users can see each user documents in one place. Now if a user wants to access another user's document, he should not go through all the normal manual process of authorization that is carried out by Google. He should just get access to that document. I have seen this functionality in the alfresco CMS that users can see and grant access without manual authorization. Let me know how I can get this facility.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps business accounts are what you need. Users within the same domain are able to access each others documents after the regular authorization flow.